# How can I show the window print dialog using JavaScript in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I’m using JavaScrpt `window.print()` function to print out the document. But here is a problem in Google Chrome when `window.print()` function is run it shows the Chrome print dialog not window print dialog. How can I show the window print dialog in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

It is behaving correctly see this for more information.

> The window object represents an open window in a browser.
>
> If a document contain frames ( tags), the browser creates one window object for the HTML document, and one additional window object for each frame.

[source.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)